# Circular Dependancies in android layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I've spent the last hour trying to find where I've got a circular dependancy in my layout, but i can't find it anywhere.

Can someone see where my problem lies? The Logcat doesn't seem to provide an exact line on where it it throwing the error.

Layout XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="au.gov.nsw.shellharbour.saferroadsshellharbour.Report_a_Hazard"
    android:background="@drawable/background">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="350dp"
                android:id="@+id/CapturedImage"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Choose Existing"
                android:id="@+id/btn_Choose_existing"
                android:layout_below="@+id/CapturedImage"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/view"
                android:background="#0000FF"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:id="@+id/view"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Take Photo"
                android:id="@+id/btn_take_photo"
                android:layout_below="@+id/CapturedImage"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/view"
                android:background="#0000FF"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Location_input"
                android:layout_below="@+id/btn_Choose_existing"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:editable="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Location_label"
                android:text="Name"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Location_input"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Location_input"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/PhoneNumber_input"
                android:editable="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/Location_input"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:background="@drawable/abc_menu_hardkey_panel_holo_light"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/PhoneNumber_label"
                android:text="Phone Number"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/PhoneNumber_input"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/PhoneNumber_input"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/HazardType_Label"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/HazardType_Label"
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Hazard_details_label"
                android:text="Hazard Details"
                android:layout_below="@+id/PhoneNumber_input"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/NumberandStreet_input"
                android:editable="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/AdditionalInfo_label"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:background="@drawable/abc_menu_hardkey_panel_holo_light"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/NumberandStreet_label"
                android:text="Number and Street"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/NumberandStreet_input"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/NumberandStreet_input"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Suburb_input"
                android:editable="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/NumberandStreet_input"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:background="@drawable/abc_menu_hardkey_panel_holo_light"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Suburb_Label"
                android:text="Suburb"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Suburb_input"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Suburb_input"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/HazardType_input"
                android:editable="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/Suburb_input"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:background="@drawable/abc_menu_hardkey_panel_holo_light"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/HazardType_Label"
                android:text="Type of Hazard"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/HazardType_input"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/HazardType_input"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/AdditionalInfo_label"
                android:text="Additional Information"
                android:layout_below="@+id/HazardType_input"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/AdditionalInfo_input"
                android:editable="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/AdditionalInfo_label"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:background="@drawable/abc_menu_hardkey_panel_holo_light"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Back"
                android:id="@+id/btn_Back"
                android:layout_below="@+id/AdditionalInfo_input"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/view2"
                android:background="#0000FF"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:id="@+id/view2"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/AdditionalInfo_input"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Send Email"
                android:id="@+id/btn_Send_email"
                android:layout_below="@+id/AdditionalInfo_input"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/view2"
                android:background="#0000FF"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>




        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Logcat:

```
10-21 13:39:41.731  29163-29163/au.gov.nsw.shellharbour.saferroadsshellharbour E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout$DependencyGraph.getSortedViews(RelativeLayout.java:1321)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.sortChildren(RelativeLayout.java:316)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:337)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15371)
            at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1466)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:388)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15371)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:617)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:399)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15371)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4876)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15371)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:833)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15371)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4876)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2423)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15371)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2003)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1242)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1417)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1135)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4635)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4963)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

As i previously stated, I've spent well over an hour trying to find the problem, and I'm still beating my head trying to find it. the only thing i can think of is that my layout positioning is wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know what happen to my previous answer that got deleted :S

The problem are those 4 relationships

```
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/NumberandStreet_input"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/AdditionalInfo_label" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Suburb_input"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/NumberandStreet_input" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/HazardType_input"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Suburb_input" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/AdditionalInfo_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/HazardType_input"
            android:text="Additional Information" />
```

- **NumberandStreet_input** below `AdditionalInfo_label`
- `AdditionalInfo_label` below `HazardType_input`
- `HazardType_input` below `Suburb_input`
- `Suburb_input` below **NumberandStreet_input**

It took me a long while to find the dependency. I strongly suggest you to tidy up your layout, there are a lot of common style attributes that should be grouped in a style to make the layout more readable. If I were you I would rewrite the layout, most likely you can accomplish the same layout without the need of so many below, righto, leftto, etc which makes it really hard when you need to move something because every component position is dependent to the others

Answer (score 0):

here

```
<TextView 
                android:id="@+id/AdditionalInfo_label"
                android:layout_below="@+id/HazardType_input"

<EditText
                android:id="@+id/HazardType_input"
                android:layout_below="@+id/Suburb_input"

<EditText
                android:id="@+id/Suburb_input"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/NumberandStreet_input"
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/NumberandStreet_input"
            android:layout_below="@+id/AdditionalInfo_label"
```

1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 1 follow layout_bellow :D